# Finding the numbers or alphabets based on thier position in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have following as a sample cell value(each value is different for my data):

ABC-A1-G3-112233-223344-556677

I want to separate the values in their different respective columns so that:

ABC will appear in column G

A1 will appear in column H

G3 will appear in column I

112233 will appear in column J

.
.
.
.
So on..

Much appreciate your assistance.

Thank you

Comment: SO expects original poster to work on his/her solution and then asking for specific help. Please try yourself to build a code and then post. This also can be solved by a formula as well.

Comment: You say that "each value is different for my data". Will all rows always have 6 fields (separated by 5 dashes)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Text to Columns:

- Select the includes the string
- Go to Data - Text to Columns
- Select Delimited, press next
- Select Other and import "-", press next

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty but if you are looking for something to drag down in each column, the below will work (albeit, messy).

You'll notice that other than the first one (column G) the rest are the same with the [instance_num] of the 3 SUBSTITUTEs changed per formula. It is essentially finding the 1st instance of the hyphen and the 2nd instance and returning the middle text. Then the text between 2nd and 3rd instance, then text between 3rd and 4th, etc.

Column G should really be =LEFT() but I have it as a =MID() to try keep it somewhat standard.

Column G formula;

```
=MID($A1,1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),1))-1)
```

Column H formula;

```
=MID($A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),1))-1)
```

Column I formula;

```
=MID($A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

Column J formula;

```
=MID($A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),4))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",CHAR(1),3))-1)
```

Comment: You can use this single formula `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("-"&$A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99*COLUMNS($A$1:A1),99))` to achieve the same results. Copy down and across. Check Rick Rothstein's corner on Excel Fox for logic.